# emmet-vim: nested numbering and rebasing

Tags: html, vim, emmet

I would like to obtain the following snippet where numbering resets in nested `<p>`tags.

```
<div class="1">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        <p class="a1"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="b1"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="a2"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="b2"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<div class="2">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        <p class="a1"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="b1"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="a2"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="b2"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</div>
```

To achieve this result I tried `(div.$ > (p.a$@1 + p.b$@1)*2)*2` translating to:

```
<div class="1">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         <p class="a1"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="b1"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<div class="2">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         <p class="a2"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="b2"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      </div>
```

and `(div.$ > (p.a$ + p.b$)@1*2)*2`translating to:

```
<div class="1">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        <p class="a1"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="b1"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<div class="2">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        <p class="a2"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <p class="b2"></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</div>
```

~

How should I use the rebasing `@`tag to obtain the result?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
(div.i_$$>(p.a_$$+p.b_$$)*2)*2
```

```html
<div class="i_01">
  <p class="a_01"></p>
  <p class="b_01"></p>
  <p class="a_02"></p>
  <p class="b_02"></p>
</div>
<div class="i_02">
  <p class="a_01"></p>
  <p class="b_01"></p>
  <p class="a_02"></p>
  <p class="b_02"></p>
</div>
```